# Can I place a subpanel next to a water pipe?

Tags: electrical

My main panel is full so I need to install a sub panel, the issue is the water main comes in right next to it:
[image]

I don't think I can install a panel directly to the left (subpanel A) because the water pipe below would restrict access to it, but that would be the most convenient location.  Alternatively, could it be installed to the right of the pex pipe (subpanel B) if I put a wall similar to the one the main panel is on?

Comment: How much distance is there between the wall and the water pipe, and how far does the backer board stand the existing main panel off the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the main panel is mounted on a plywood sheet which is SOP... but then, it also looks like the plywood sheet is pushed out on a 2x4? riser.  I would continue that framing-and-plywood treatment to the right, moving that conduit and receptacle as needed. (Heck, just move that conduit and recep to the new panel).

As far as the water valve, I'd look at how far out it comes from the wall, and run it by your AHJ.  The panel face will already be 7+ inches proud of the wall, and nobody stands so close that their toes are planar to the panel face. *That would be too close to work IMO*.  So I would ask the AHJ for a variance, and just put the subpanel right next to the panel (or as close as will fit).

The framing is not actualy required for a panel.  You can fix it directly to the wall, but the better plan is to fit at least a sheet of 1" plywood - 4' x 4' would be a good sheet size.

I like the idea of having the second panel on plywood that is continuous with the first panel, simply because it will make the conduit work easier.  Running one or more conduit pipes will solve a lot of wiring problems, and if it's 24" long that works better, because the rules are liberalized for such a short "nipple".

Remember to get a large enough panel.   Spaces are dirt cheap; adding a panel is expensive.  So learn the lessons from the overfill and don't ever let it happen again.  I would go with at least a 24-space.  Also, if you have a mind to add a generator at some point, pick a Square D "QO" or a Siemens, as generator interlocks are easier on these (however they take up 4 spaces).

Answer (score 1):

The code requires a 30" wide 36" deep working space in front of the panel which can be measured from either edge of the panel. The vertical pipe would likely not be an issue, but for location A the horizontal stuff on the floor would be.

You can mount directly to the concrete if you have the tools, but that creates difficulty securing the cables where they leave the panel.

You may need to consider how you local Authority Having Jurisdiction interprets the NEC section prohibiting using NM cable were subject to physical damage. Some jurisdictions have adopted specific local codes that specify everything less than 7 or 8 feet is considered subject to damage. The areas you show your subpanel options are lower than your service panel, and may cross the line in your AHJ's opinion.